Massive memory leak when creating and releasing Capture Filter in DirectShow
After much trial and error I have succeeded in grabbing still images from the laptop's built-in camera.
But I have noticed a memory leak and spent days trying to pin it.
So I have stripped the code to a bare-bones "leak demo". It does nothing useful otherwise - doesn't grab images, etc.
But it does connect to the camera device and create a Capture Filter - only to release it immediately.
Here is the complete code.
If the two marked lines of code are COMMENTED, there is no leak.
But if they are employed, there is a MASSIVE memory leak - hundreds of handles and approximately 2 Mb per second.
All I am doing there is creating and releasing a Capture Filter. Or so it pleases me to believe ...
#include <dshow.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "strmiids.lib")



HRESULT DisplayDeviceInfo(IEnumMoniker* EnumMoniker, _Inout_ IMoniker** Found)
{
    *Found = {};
    IBindCtx* Context = {};
    if (S_OK == CreateBindCtx({}, &Context))
    {
        IMoniker* Moniker = {};
        while (S_OK == EnumMoniker->Next(1, &Moniker, {}))
        {
            IPropertyBag* ProBag = {};
            if (S_OK == Moniker->BindToStorage(Context, {}, IID_PPV_ARGS(&ProBag)))
            {
                VARIANT V; VariantInit(&V);
                if (S_OK == ProBag->Read(L"DevicePath", &V, {}))
                {
                    wcprintf("  Path: \'%ws\'\n", V.bstrVal); *Found = Moniker;
                }
                VariantClear(&V);
                SAFERELEASE(ProBag);
                if (*Found) break;
            }
            else SAFERELEASE(ProBag);
            SAFERELEASE(Moniker);
        }
        if (!(*Found)) SAFERELEASE(Moniker);
    }
    return (*Found) ? S_OK : HRESULT(-1);
}



HRESULT LeakDemoPiece(void)
{
    auto hr = HRESULT(-1);

    ICreateDevEnum* DevEnum = NULL;
    IEnumMoniker* EnumMoniker = NULL;
    IMoniker* Device = NULL;
    IBindCtx* Context = NULL;
    IBaseFilter* CaptureFilter = NULL;

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum, {}, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&DevEnum)); if (S_OK != hr) goto Error;
    hr = DevEnum->CreateClassEnumerator(CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory, &EnumMoniker, {}); if (S_OK != hr) goto Error;
    hr = DisplayDeviceInfo(EnumMoniker, &Device); if (S_OK != hr) goto Error;
    hr = CreateBindCtx({}, &Context); if (S_OK != hr) goto Error;
    
    // Un-commenting the two lines below causes a massive memory leak (but no errors) - why ???
    // 
    // hr = Device->BindToObject(Context, {}, IID_PPV_ARGS(&CaptureFilter)); if (S_OK != hr) goto Error;
    // SAFERELEASE(CaptureFilter);

    goto CleanupAndExit;

Error:

    wcprintf("\n\tERROR 0x%lX\n", hr);

CleanupAndExit:

    SAFERELEASE(CaptureFilter);
    SAFERELEASE(Context);
    SAFERELEASE(Device);
    SAFERELEASE(EnumMoniker);
    SAFERELEASE(DevEnum);
    return hr;
}



int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE dummy, _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow)
{
    if (SUCCEEDED(CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE)))
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < 1024; n++)
        {
            LeakDemoPiece();
            Sleep(100);
        }
        CoUninitialize();
    }
    else MessageBox({}, L"CoInitializeEx(...) failed\n\nin wWinMain(...)", L"ERROR", MB_ICONERROR | MB_APPLMODAL);
    return NULL;
}

What am I missing?
I couldn't find anything on the Microsoft COM/Winapi documentation that would give me a clue?
Please someone tell me what could be happening here?
Thank you!
In my perhaps naive  assumption, if one creates a COM object and then releases it immediately, it should not result in things like hundreds of orphaned handles and megabytes of abandoned allocated memory.
I have tried this demo piece on different laptops with different SDKs - and the leak is there.

I think the code is fine. It does not build :) and needs updates, but still. The leak might be caused by some third party software items that extends DirectShow. Some, e.g. virtual camera software installed at all systems you tried this on.

I ran it. There are only slight changes in heap size and process memory.

Thank you for your reply! I feel much better. Having looked at one of the laptops, I have discovered a few questionable drivers that beg for removal.
